# MATLAB date conversion with format 1999M03

Tags: matlab

I am trying to figure out what format should I use when converting a date string of the format (Note there is a M between year number and month number)

```
1999M03
```

or equivalently `yyyyMmm` to a date number using the MATLAB `datenum` function. Clearly,

```
datenum(dstring, 'yyyyMmm')
```

returns error message

```
Error using datenum (line 178)
DATENUM failed.

Caused by:
    Error using cnv2icudf (line 131)
    Unrecognized minute format.  Format string: yyyyMmm.
```

and using escaping character

```
datenum(dstring, 'yyyy\Mmm')
```

does not help here. Please feel free to comment. I highly appreciate your kind help.

Sam

Comment: Would this work? - `datenum(regexprep('1999M03', 'M', '-'))` What's the output that you are expecting?

Comment: What does this `M` stands for? is it March? May? or just 'Month' - functioning as a seperator?

Comment: @Shai Given the way the question is asked, I suspect `M` stands for "Month" and is just a separator. The OP mentioned `yyyyMmm` as a date format, where `mm` is presumably between `01` and `12`.